# "instead of" vs. "rather than" when choosing words

Tags: word-usage

A [VOA tutorial](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/blinding-lights-and-english-grammar-/5324879.html) says

> teachers and test graders want to see the words trying to **instead of** tryna.

I understand this sentence clearly.

I just wondering whether "**rather than**" could be substituted for "**instead of**".

I [searched a bit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22instead%20of%22%20and%20%22rather%20than%22) and [one of the answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/205113/109190) gives some clear rules (I modified it a little bit)

> (rule#1) "*Instead of*" is used when you were given a plan and you want to change it.
>
> (rule#2) "*Rather than*" connotes a situation where you are asked about something and you like both options and you need to choose your favorite.

I suppose most VOA articles use the correct words though, the use of words does not seem to be a plan. That is more like the rule#2.

Which rule is supposed to be used in this context? Are "instead of" and "rather than" interchangeable in the case?

Comment: @Fermichem Thanks. However, my OP is not a duplicate of your link. First of all, that post does not have a full context. Furthermore, that post does not show any effort before the inquirer post the question. Last, that post does not give any rules for the use "*Instead of*".

Comment: @Fermichem Thanks. The 3rd link you posted does not even mention "*rather than*" al all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The words "rather than", "instead of" and "in place of" are interchangeable when you are talking about alternatives.

consider this example where all three are possible.

> Robots  are  used in industry  In place of/instead of/rather than humans.

There really isn't much of a difference in meaning between the three, except perhaps **rather than** implies **preference** whereas **instead of** implies **substitution**, however even that is not considered a big of difference.

ref: https://wikidiff.com/instead/rather

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you please link some authoritative reference?

Comment: The quora link conveys more information. Thank you so much. In my OP, is the choice of words a matter of "preference" or a matter of "substitution"?

Comment: I guess it's a matter of substitution since teachers prefer to see "trying to" as opposed to "tryna". In other words, they'd like to see A in place of B, where A is "trying to" and B is "tryna".

Comment: Well, it might also be reasonable to consider it as a matter of "preference", the teachers' preference. As you said "teachers **prefer** ...", right?

Comment: I do know that in many cases there's no difference between them. even some English text books such as AMEF and Viewpoint mention the same thing. take a look at viewpoint 2 lesson 9 writing for instance (PDF is available)

Comment: Thank you, that's very kind of you. Would you please give a link about that?